# What does a .feature represent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What does a .feature represent? I came across this while I was learning Ruby on Rails. I am not sure if this is a question or scenario

Comment: Here's a link to the [cucumber .feature file documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Introduction), which is chock full of good information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .feature file is from [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) testing suite, Cucumber is a way of doing integration testing on your ruby on rails application.